# H2 RUNSCRIPT equivalent in HSQL

Tags: java, hsqldb

In H2, it is easy to setup in-mem db for unit testing via RUNSCRIPT command as part of connection url itself (No hibernate & Spring required) to set it up.

**h2 sample**

```
jdbc:h2:mem:sample;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:scripts/create.sql'\\;RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:scripts/create_2.sql'
```

I am trying to understand if there is a way to have a similar setup for hsqldb too? No success till now. If it is in documentation, point me to the specific link please.

Constraints:

1. HSQL should be in-memory only.
2. No Spring and Hibernate should be used.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSQLDB supports a memory database that is read from file, with no change automatically written to file.

Create the memory database with tables and required initial data, then save it with the `SRCIPT 'filename'` command.

Then open it as a file readonly database:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:filename;files_readonly=true
```

Comment: One question, it hsql a load of files in the folder, I read the sql file from.like .lck, .properties, .log, .script a folder too. Why is that so, and how can it be avoided.

Comment: You can execute SHUTDOWN to remove the .lck and .log files.